# Why is the screen rotation slow and freezing the screen?

Tags: performance, samsung-galaxy-note, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1, auto-rotation

I have a Samsung Galaxy note 10.1, and the screen rotation before was noticeably quicker. It just recently started to take another second or two to rotate. On top of that, everything on screen will freeze until the animation is complete. I am not rubbing that many applications when this happens. It will happen even if I reboot. I am using only a forth of the ram and storage and power saving mode is off. What could cause this, and is it fixable?

Comment: Did you change settings somewhere? Animations is one are I could think of under Developer options in settings (If you don't have that, disregard that option). Other than that, was it recently updated? Did you install a app on prior occasion (most recently)?

Comment: Developer options are disabled, and I don't think I ever messed with them. I uninstalled same of the most recent apps and delete some old downloaded files. It's set up for auto update and I don't ever remember seeing a notification so it most have been up to days since I got it.

Comment: Maybe a factory reset might do the trick (*you will lose everything*) - **caveat emptor**

Comment: Would it be possible to use the back up to get them back, or does the reset wipe that?

Comment: Can you clarify what are you referring to in relation to backup? Do you mean CWM/TWRP nandroid backup or adb backup?

Comment: Settings - backup and reset. I'm not familiar with all the methods just the one in settings next to factory reset.

Comment: That option is similar to the principle in performing a backup see [this question about backing up](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices) The factory reset option wipes all user data and restores the device to the original state as when it left the factory. As my previous comments above, carries that caveat emptor...